# Postgresql/ database - traceout on graph with stop criterium (topology)

Tags: database, postgresql, graph, psql, topology

I have a undirected graph and want to make a traceout. This works fine with:

```
    WITH RECURSIVE path AS (
     SELECT edge_id, start_node, end_node
       FROM simulation.edge_data
       WHERE start_node = 1 OR end_node = 1
     UNION
     SELECT e.edge_id, e.start_node, e.end_node
       FROM simulation.edge_data e, path s
       WHERE s.start_node = e.start_node OR s.start_node = e.end_node OR s.end_node = e.end_node OR s.end_node = e.start_node) 
    SELECT * FROM path;
```

1. Now I want to stop at certain nodes if the corresponding record of the node has the status = closed.
2. Not further investigate on not reachable nodes.

I tried to add something in the where clause:

```
    (SELECT status FROM getRecord(e.start_node)) = open
```

This gives me all the correct nodes but not all edges.
I can provide more code if needed dont want to overdo if the answer is quiet simple!

[image]

Comment: `WHERE s.start_node = e.start_node OR s.start_node = e.end_node OR s.end_node = e.end_node OR s.end_node = e.start_node)` You will run into a cycle with length=2 here.

Comment: How can i improved that?

Comment: By excluding the points (or edges) that you have already visited (or walked). You'll need to maintain a collection (array) of visited points for this.